# Handling Multiple Mouse Events in MVVM in WPF

Tags: mvvm, mouseevent

I am following the below discussion, 
[Handling Mouse Events in MVVM in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260946/handling-mouse-events-in-mvvm-in-wpf/54744819)
It is working for one event but when I try to multiple events, it is not working.

```
I want to bind multiple events like below:

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger 
     EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TripLegCopyIconPressedCommand}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding 
               TripLegPreviewMouseLeftButtonUpCommand}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

But it is not working. How to do that? Any idea?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, multiple event binding will work and not recommended.