# How would you interact with a WPF Canvas with MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

Almost all examples of MVVM are applications that have View that may consist of ListBoxes, TextBoxes, Labels, Buttons, etc. to present and process data. ListBoxes, TextBoxes, and Labels are bound to properties and Buttons are bound to Commands in a ViewModel. Those types of Views are mainly static in nature.

However, there are not any real examples of how to deal with a fluid View, such as a drawing program. When you think about it, a drawing program is just a Canvas. Because there are no Buttons to which to bind nor Listboxes, TextBoxes, or Labels to interact with, how should you interact with the Canvas?

So far, the only way that I have found to interact with the Canvas is to use the Canvas' code-behind to use the Mouse Events to allow you to pass data into the ViewModel through exposed methods such as Add(Point point) which will add a point to an ObservableCollection only to be bound to an ItemsControl that will process the point data based on the ItemTemplate.

**CanvasView**

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasObjectModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="1000" Height="1000" Background="GhostWhite"
                MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown"/>-->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Origin.X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Origin.Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CanvasObject:Node Origin="{Binding Origin}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**IMyCanvas**

```cs
public interface IMyCanvas
{
    public void AddCanvasObject(Point origin);
}
```

**CanvasView Code-Behind**

```cs
public partial class CanvasView : UserControl
{
    private IMyCanvas pViewModel;

    public CanvasView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += InitializeViewModel;
    }

    private void InitializeViewModel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext is IMyCanvas viewModel)
            pViewModel = viewModel;
        else
            throw new Exception("DataContext does not implement IMyCanvas!");
            
        Loaded -= InitializeViewModel;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = sender as Canvas;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            pViewModel.AddCanvasObject(e.GetPosition(canvas));
        }
    }
}
```

**CanvasObjectModel**

```cs
public class CanvasObjectModel
{
    public Point Origin { get; set; }
}
```

**CanvasViewModel**

```cs
internal class CanvasViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMyCanvas
{
    public ObservableCollection<CanvasObjectModel> CanvasObjectModels { get; set; }

    public CanvasViewModel()
    {
        CanvasObjectModels = new ObservableCollection<CanvasObjectModel>();
    }

    public void AddCanvasObject(Point origin)
    {
        CanvasObjectModels.Add(new CanvasObjectModel() { Origin = origin});
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: the main problem is to bind mouse events to some commands in your ViewModel?

Comment: *"interact with the Canvas is to use the Canvas' code-behind to use the Mouse Events to allow you to pass data into the ViewModel through exposed methods"* - That's absolutely fine. *"When you think about it, a drawing program is just a Canvas"* - That's not quite right. A drawing is a complex object similar to any other object in that it is described by a rendered  object based on a data object or data model.

Comment: For example a line has the data level attributes like a start and end  point. It has a thickness an a color. All the data you need in order to restore the original line e.g. after a restart. Then to that data layer maps the rendering layer that contains an object that the framework is able to render. WPF provides multiple ways on different abstraction levels.

Comment: For example a Shape object belongs to the simplest and highest or most abstract level. You have to map the data model of the line to a visual like a Line the same way a collection of data models maps to a ListBox. Everything you can see is rendered. It doesn't matter if it is a ListBox or a Shape. All rendered objects are usually view of an associated date model. The View of a drawing program would usually contain a lot more then simply a Canvas.

Comment: I have a sort of drawing app, our map editor. That has an inkcanvas you draw in. Once you finish a stroke there's an event raised. I work with the stroke and translate it into points which are then used in a geometry. Beneath the inkcanvas is an itemscontrol with a canvas as itemspanel. I template out viewmodels containing geometries into things in that canvas. I could dig out some code if it helps but there's quite a lot of it.

Comment: You can compare it with a RichtTextEditor. You need a control (RichTextBox) which can edit the data and the ViewModel gets notified about the changes. So you need (to build) an editor control for drawing.

Comment: I would not try to bind this

Comment: @Joe, care to elaborate as to why you would not try to bind this?

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Not only did I somehow not finish that comment.  I put it under the wrong post.  What I meant was in regards to GeorgeKarlinzer's answer.    I meant to say that I would not try to bind drawing to *commands* because of the need to maintain *state* during drawing (is the mouse down, is it captured, etc) and the inherent "click" nature of commands

Comment: @Joe, do you have a suggestion as to how you would go about doing this? Is there a better way than how I shown in my OP?

Comment: I am afraid not.  I myself have developed a `MultiSelector` control with a `Canvas` that permits the user to draw, select, drag and resize shapes.    Been improving it over the years.  While it works fairly well, I find I am still more knowledgeable in how I should *not*  implement its features than how I should.

Comment: Sometimes I ask myself "Why insist to use MVVM when is not necessary?". When you want a super dynamic UI like a canvas in which user paint something maybe C# is your friend and XAML is a useless tight constraint. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind events to VM commands you can use Interactivity:

```xaml
<Canvas Width="1000" Height="1000" Background="GhostWhite">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Canvas/>
```

For more information you can check [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260946/handling-mouse-events-in-mvvm-in-wpf)

Comment: Interactivity looks to be a NuGet package. Is this official code from Microsoft? Also, based on this link [https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) it looks like this is no longer used, and according to this link [github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3400](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3400) they look to show to use **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf** as an alternative, which looks like it is shown in an answer by [Kaloyan Manev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9665681/kaloyan-manev).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CallMethodAction` behavior from `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` [(NuGet Package)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) to directly call your view model methods from XAML.

I am giving you a button example but you can handle the events of your canvas in the same way

**1. Add this namespace to your XAML:**

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

**2. Add the *CallMethodAction*  trigger to your button in XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="button">
  <Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=button}">
      <Behaviors:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="IncrementCount"/>
    </Behaviors:EventTrigger>
  </Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**3. Place a IncrementCount method in your view model:**

```
public int Count { get; set; }

public void IncrementCount()
{
    Count++;
}
```

Now you can skip the boilerplate code in the code behind. Also, you can check the XamlBehaviorsWpf wiki here: https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki There are some other behaviors as well :)

Comment: Is Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf official Microsoft code?

Comment: Yes.  It is a NuGet package published by Microsoft.  If you look at the github page, you will see that it was most recently updated 4 months ago